# Can't add ImageCropper as property in Umbraco LeBlender grid editor

Tags: umbraco

I'm trying to add Image Cropper data type as a property in a LeBlender custom grid editor.

I have Image Cropper as a DataType.

[image]

But it doesn't show up in the LeBlender property when trying to choose it as a data type.

[image]

I would appreciate if anyone would explain what is wrong and what is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think LeBlender allows all text-based (plain, XML, JSON) property types.  I think an image or image cropper would not qualify, and is accordingly not a choice.  Could you use a Media Picker, or perhaps a custom Media Picker associated with your image cropper?

You could ask this question in the GitHub issues for the LeBlender, too.  I searched issues for 'image', but found nothing helpful.

https://github.com/Lecoati/LeBlender/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=image

, Lee

Comment: Indeed it seems to not be possible to use ImageCropper inside LeBlender even if used in another DataType and used inside LeBlender....  
https://our.umbraco.com/packages/backoffice-extensions/leblender/general-discussion/67645-image-cropper-in-leblender